# Formula relating angle between intersection of curves in map to that of surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose we have a surface $S$ whose metric is given:
$$ds^2 =A^2 du^2 + Bdv^2 + 2F du dv$$

Let's say I have two curves in the $u-v$ plane which intersect at an angle $\theta$, suppose I have two curves intersecting at a point with angle $\theta$ between their tangent vectors, then is there any way to figure out at what angle the curves corresponding to those curves intersect with on the surface?

The one thing I do know is that if we have a conformal mapping i.e: a metric of form $d \hat{s} = \lambda(z) ds^2 $(where ds is the separation in plane) then the angle in the map and on surface are same.

Comment: You need more information than just the angle. You need the actual tangent vectors. That's the whole point of the first fundamental form: It tells you the formula for dot product.

Comment: I mean , let it be two arbitrary tangent vectors in the plane $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$, what next? @TedShifrin